# Visual Studio 2019 and GIT - losing references after changing branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

From a few weeks now, I'm having issues with VS2019 and GIT.
Everytime I switch between branches, using Fork as GIT client, is like VS2019 does not update project references and i start to have miss references issues.
I had to close, re-open VS2019 and rebuild/build the project.
Any ideias on this?